# Bootstrap-table, generating a printed report using server side pagination

Tags: bootstrap-table

Looking for ideas/suggestions on how to print the table with using server side pagination.  Not surprising using the data-show-print only prints the current page of data in the DOM.  However, the table consists of thousands of records potentially depending on the if search criteria is sent to data-ajax or not.  Which is why I have opted for server side pagination.  Otherwise, if I used client side pagination, the page become unresponsive if it returns that much data at once.

I have performed many Google searches but haven't come up with anything specific to others having this issue.  Which seems a bit strange.  I would expect others to have run across this situation.  Which makes me wonder what am I missing?

If someone has an example or can point me in the right direction on how to deal with this use case, I'd be much appreciative!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Have you considered using the Export plugin in addition to or instead of the Print plugin? You can export to pdf, for example, and then that could be printed.

When using export, there is an option [setDataType](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/export/#exportdatatype) which by default is set to `basic` but if changed to `all` will export all of the records.

For reference, [this export example from the documentation](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/extensions/export.html) uses server side pagination. If `all` is selected instead of `basic` and then the table is exported, all of the records will be there.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have looked at the export feature.  However, from the functionality of it thus far, I don't see how to customize the output.  For example, there are no totals at the bottom which I have in the footer of the table.   In addition, when executed, the entire page locks up while it's processing the data.  Would need at least a spinner going to let the user know the system is processing the request.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can certainly export the footer as well using the `data-export-footer` option. [See the docs here.](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/export/) Interesting that it locks up, but you're right I just tried it with about 6000 records and it does. Further down on the page linked above there are two events that can fire before the export and when it is done. Those could likely be used to make a spinner appear while processing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I see the events.  Any idea how those are accessed? It mentions JQuery event.  Meaning I need to use JQuery to access it?  Or perhaps the onExportStarted is part of the table configuration as one of the parameters and define a function to call. ie.  onExportStarted: function (arg1, arg2) { ... }. Thoughts?

Comment: So far I've noticed that when I try to export to pdf using data-export-types="['pdf']", it doesn't export the table data as shown. 1st I noticed that it is re-sorting the data by date in ascending order instead of how it is shown in the table.  In my example, I have the data sorted descending by date.  Also, it only gives 10 pages of output.  Where there is much more data.  The paginated table data shoes 1963 pages.  So I'm not sure what might going on here.  Ideas?

Comment: For events, they are accessed the same way as the normal BSTable events. [Event documentation here](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/) So yes, I believe what you said at the end should work. The other behavior is curious, as it seems to work [in this modified example](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/nickjrotundo/15766) selecting "all" and then sorting a column yields a pdf with all pages and the sorting still active. Are you using other extension that could maybe cause some conflict?

Comment: Ok.  I had a default of 500 record limit in my SQL statement which was the limiting factor.

Comment: I found another isse, perhaps you can help.  When the export is executing I need to know on the backend if the call is a request for the export or a request data for the table on-screen.  I'd like to pass a query parameter but haven't find a good way to identify when the export is happening.  I tried using the export-started.bs.table and export-saved.bs.table events by setting a variable true on the started event and then false on the save event.  But it seems once I click the export button it remains true so that is not helping me differentiate between the two types of ajax calls.  Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of setting a variable, you could use the event itself to pass the parameter to show it being an export. Otherwise, you will know it's a table load.